# Protractor on offline app? Does it work?

Tags: automated-testing, protractor

I was wondering is there anyway to do E2E testing for an offline app with protractor? I cache my pages in the application cache and store data using localForage, testing it online is fine, but I also need to test it offline, is this even possible? If not what are the solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test offline as Web Driver needs to connect to the server. You would have to test locally.There are other options like either testing this manually ,Create a JS script to turn off internet connection or create spec that can do the E2E flow as long as the application is designed to work in offline mode.

I would have entire project locally installed and then write e2e test using my local machine.The issue is having the test run on a production server which is quite difficult to test.